# Send command and wait for reply - Wait for delegate in Obj-C

Tags: ios, delegates, wait

My goal is to achieve synchronized communication to custom **Device** i.e. next command can be send only when reply is received. Now I'm doing it in this way

**Device** class implements **DeviceDelegate** protocol

```
//Device.h
@class Device;

@protocol DeviceDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didReciveReplyWithData:(NSData *)data;
@end

@interface Device : NSObject {}
```

In **DeviceViewController** implementation:

```
@interface DeviceViewController()
{
    BOOL waitingForReply = false;
}
@end

@implementation DeviceViewController

- (void)sendCommandWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    if ( waitingForReply == false)
    {
        //send command code
        waitingForReply = true;
    }
}

- (void)didReciveReplyWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    //code
    waitingForReply = false;
}

@end
```

but I wish to do it in more elegant way i.e. by using GCD (semaphores?) with blocks (completionHandler?). Any ideas?

PS. Sorry, but I forgot to mention: all commands sended to device while

```
waitingForReply = true
```

**should be ignored!!!**.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the best approach here would be to create a queue of commands with [`NSOperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html).

Since, presumably, the communication with the device is asynchronous you will have to subclass [`NSOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/index.html) to encapsulate the communication.

```
@interface DeviceCommandOperation : NSOperation <DeviceDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL waitingForReply;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSData *dataToSend;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSData *dataReceived;
@end

@implementation DeviceCommandOperation

- (instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)dataToSend
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _dataToSend = [dataToSend copy];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setWaitingForReply:(BOOL)waitingForReply
{
    if (_waitingForReply != waitingForReply)
    {
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

        _waitingForReply = waitingForReply;

        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
        [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];

    }
}

- (void)start
{
    self.waitingForReply = YES;

    // Simulate sending a command and waiting for response.
    // You will need to replace this with your actual communication mechanism.
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // In reality this call would presumably come from the Device
        [self didReceiveReplyWithData:someData];
    });
}

- (void)didReceiveReplyWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    self.dataReceived = data;
    self.waitingForReply = NO;
}

#pragma mark - NSOperation

- (BOOL)isAsynchronous
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)isExecuting
{
    return _waitingForReply;
}

- (BOOL)isFinished
{
    return !_waitingForReply;
}

@end
```

This operation *could* then be used from your `DeviceViewController` (it would probably be better architecturally to have this responsibility elsewhere but that's not the topic of this question).

```
@interface DeviceViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;
@end

@implementation DeviceViewController

- (NSOperationQueue *)operationQueue
{
    if (_operationQueue == nil)
    {
        _operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    }
    return _operationQueue;
}

- (void)sendNextCommand
{
    NSData *data = // Get data for the next command
    [self sendCommandWithData:data];
}

- (void)sendCommandWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Queueing operation");

    DeviceCommandOperation *operation = [[DeviceCommandOperation alloc] initWithData:data];

    // The operation's completionBlock gets called on a background queue
    [operation setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"DeviceCommandOperation completed");

        // Process operation.dataReceived

        [self sendNextCommand];
    }];

    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}

@end
```

This approach will allow you to determine what (if any) command to send next, based on the reply to the previous command.

If you know all of the "commands" you will want to send initially and don't need finer grained control you could create instances of `DeviceCommandOperation` for each command, set the queue's `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1, and add each `DeviceCommandOperation` to the queue (in the order you want them to be processed).